# Images in Shiny through R package

Tags: r, image, shiny

My images are not displaying when I use shiny in a R package structure.

Within my R directory, I have a file myApp.R with a general outline as follows:

```
@param1
myFunction = function(param1){
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(...)
  body <- dashboardBody(...)
  ui <- dashboardPage(...)
  server <- function(input, output, session) { img(src='Figure1.png')}
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

I tried having Figure1.png inside R/www and also in inst/www, but neither location seemed to create the figures when I ran myFunction(param1). It would create the general application - but the images would just be absent.

Is there a simple workaround for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: try `.png` and `.PNG`

Comment: Thanks @PorkChop. I tried changing src='Figure1.png' to src='Figure1.PNG' and also changed the actual files to have .PNG instead of .png extensions - but it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the function addResourcePath("www", "www") and refer to the image with www/Figure1.png

Andrew

Comment: Thanks @awchisholm, I may be misunderstanding... but I added addResourcePath("www", "www") to the first line within myFunction() and also as the first line within server <- function(input, output, session) {}. In both cases, I received the error: "Error in normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : path[1]="www": No such file or directory"

Comment: The second parameter is a full path; so perhaps something like ‘/home/user/www’

Comment: Thanks again. It now works on my system. However, I am concerned this will not work as a package function as I planning to submit it to CRAN. I don't think I could use an absolute reference because of that.

Comment: If you have files released with the package you could use the system.file() function to find the path of the file at run time and use this in the call to addResourcePath.

Comment: e.g. shiny::addResourcePath('www', system.file('www', package = 'MyPackage'))

Answer (score 2):

A working example can be found by Divad Nojnarg's "[CaPO4 sim](https://github.com/DivadNojnarg/CaPO4Sim)", as described in an [issue I raised](https://github.com/RinteRface/shinydashboardPlus/issues/42) about referring to a local icon file in the shinydashboardPlus user description.

In summary, one way to reference local image files is by adding a `zzz.R` file

```
.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  shiny::addResourcePath('icons',
                         system.file("www/assets/icons",
                                      package = "DailyMeasure"))
}
```

where my package-name is **DailyMeasure**.

My image file is in `inst/www/assets/icons/user-avatar.svg`.

The file is referenced in the server section of Shiny like this...

```
output$user <- shinydashboardPlus::renderUser({
  shinydashboardPlus::dashboardUser(
    name = UserConfig()$Fullname[UserConfig()$AuthIdentity == Sys.info()[["user"]]],
    src = 'icons/user-avatar.svg', # this depends on addResourcePath in zzz.R
    subtitle = Sys.info()[["user"]], ... )})
```